# Use of have and what if

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, word-order

What if I don't have an apple phone but I have apple gloves. 
Is it correct?

Comment: You'll have to be clearer about what you're trying to say. It would be grammatical with **an Apple phone** instead of **apple phone**; but whether it means what you want - whether you understand "what if" - we can't tell.

Comment: I wanna say that I don't have an apple phone but I have Apple gloves.

Comment: In that case, you don't mean _What if_. What if introduces a hypothetical condition.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an apple phone but I have apple gloves. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you explain how could I use 'what if' in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What if I don't have an Apple phone but I have Apple gloves* is a perfectly grammatical, normal thing to say.

From your reply in the comment, it wasn't what you wanted to say, which was a simple statement

> I don't have an Apple phone but I have Apple gloves.

*What if* introduces a conditional, but is usually used when somebody has suggested or assumed the converse.

It might be a genuine question in a hypothetical mode:

> Next year Apple are releasing such and such on their phones. But what if I don't have an Apple phone?

If it's a real condition, it usually has a slightly sarcastic feel:

> A: I need a charger for my Apple phone. Can I use yours?
>
> B: What if I don't have an Apple phone?